# PHP Single page contact form not working

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, contacts

I've been working further into my contact form on a webpage and cannot get it to run correctly. (Via an include and running on apache2.2 local server).

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['Request_Method'] != 'POST') {
    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $self; ?>">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:100px;">
                Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input style="width:150px; height:25px;" placeholder="First Name" type="text" id="custname" name="custname">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>    
                <input style="width:150px; height:25px;" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" id="cust2name" name="cust2name">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Email:
            </td>
            <td>                
                <input style="width:250px; height:25px;" placeholder="Example@domain.com" type="text" id="custemail" name="custemail">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Subject:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input style="width:250px; height:25px;" placeholder="RE:Appointment & Contact" type="text" id="textsubject" name="textsubject">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>                
                Message:
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea id="custtext" name="custtext" placeholder="Please enter your message here..." rows="6" style="resize:none; font-family:arial; width:500px; height:75px;"cols="25"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
} else { 
    $name = $_POST['custname'];
    $email = $_POST['custemail'];
    $text = $_POST['custtext'];
    $subject = $_POST['textsubject'];
    $emailto = "reconnectsteam@hotmail.co.uk";

    $header = "From: $name <$email>\r\nReply-To: $email\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

    $message = "From: $name, Email: $email<br /><hr />$text";

    $mail($emailto, $subject, $message, $header);

    echo"Your email has been sent, it will be proccessed within 48hours.";
}

?>
```

Just wondering if this code will work when launched via apache 2.2 (email will not send, but should the rest of the code still work correctly and run? at the moment it seems that it is not. Are there any mistakes? (NO DATABASE included).

Thanks,

Rec

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Watch out for email header injection.

Comment: From your local machine you cann't sent the mail. upload it on server and it will work.

Comment: In PHP, array keys are case-sensitive, so at the very least, `$_SERVER['Request_Method']` should be `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

Comment: Thanks for the info Broken Heart & jedwards, good to know. Will try it uploaded later on today. No errors just a suspected page refresh and I will add security protocols at a later date. This was just for test purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two things wrong with your code.

This line:

```
if($_SERVER['Request_Method'] != 'POST') {
```

`Request_Method` **must** be in uppercase `REQUEST_METHOD` because it is a [`superglobal`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

And the dollar `$` in front of `mail()`

```
$mail($emailto, $subject, $message, $header);
```

which should be:

```
mail($emailto, $subject, $message, $header);
```

**Reformatted and working PHP/HTML form**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $self; ?>">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:100px;">
                Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input style="width:150px; height:25px;" placeholder="First Name" type="text" id="custname" name="custname">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>    
                <input style="width:150px; height:25px;" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" id="cust2name" name="cust2name">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Email:
            </td>
            <td>                
                <input style="width:250px; height:25px;" placeholder="Example@domain.com" type="text" id="custemail" name="custemail">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Subject:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input style="width:250px; height:25px;" placeholder="RE:Appointment & Contact" type="text" id="textsubject" name="textsubject">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>                
                Message:
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea id="custtext" name="custtext" placeholder="Please enter your message here..." rows="6" style="resize:none; font-family:arial; width:500px; height:75px;"cols="25"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
} else { 
    $name = $_POST['custname'];
    $email = $_POST['custemail'];
    $text = $_POST['custtext'];
    $subject = $_POST['textsubject'];
    $emailto = "email@domain.com";

    $header = "From: $name <$email>\r\nReply-To: $email\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

    $message = "From: $name, Email: $email<br /><hr />$text";

    mail($emailto, $subject, $message, $header);

    echo "Your email has been sent, it will be proccessed within 48hours.";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answer to Your question, but some global attention / security points :).

Try to left the action empty (by default form is redirecting to the same page). Then check if every needed input was filled rather then check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'`. In that case You can fill in the form using the entered values.

For example, someone enters only name. Then mail is not send and values given by a user dissapear (someone must enter name once again). 
I would propose something like this (simple example with only one field - name)

```
$name = isset($_POST['custname']) ? $_POST['custname'] : '';
$name = htmlspecialchars($name); // !!!!!!!!!!!!!
if ($name != '' && your_valid_function($name)) { // && custmail test && other test
    SEND MAIL;
    header("Location: this_page"); // prevent refreshing this page and sending multiple mails
}
else {
    //Render form here, using $name with filled values, for example:
    echo "<form><input type=\"text\" id=\"custname\" name=\"custname\" value=\"$name\"></form>"; // notice $name here
}
```

PS. **Always use at least htmlspecialchars when using POST values** :). Be carefull with robots - form without captcha or some other security features can spam your mail box hard.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First try to replace

```
$mail($emailto,...
```

with

```
mail($emailto,...
```

(Remove the "$")

Comment: thanks for the correction. The form however still does not work correctly

Comment: Well then do what jedwards said. Replace $_SERVER['Request_Method'] with $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].